# Wordpress loop add a specific class to each 3 posts in the loop

Tags: php, wordpress, class, loops, posts

I'm using a specific loop to display 3 posts on a custom page in Wordpress. For each post I want to add a class.

Post 1: .post-1

Post 2: .post-2

Post 3: .post-3

I have this loop:

```
<div class="news-wrap">
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 3 );
$lastposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach($lastposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
<div class="news-item">
    <div class="news-title"><h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3></div>
    <span class="news-date"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?></span>
    <?php html5wp_excerpt('html5wp_index'); // Build your custom callback length in functions.php ?>
</div>
```

I'm not entirely sure what to change in this loop since im pretty new to php. I found the following solution on the Wordpress forums but the code is different entirely.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php $c = 0;while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $c++;
if( $c == 3) {
$style = 'third';
$c = 0;
}
else $style='';?>
<div <?php post_class($style) ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"
```

I guess I could write if statements for 1,2,3 and the classes I want but I dont know where to start with my current loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
<div class="news-wrap">
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 3 );
$lastposts = get_posts( $args );
$index = 0;
foreach($lastposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ++$index; ?>
<div class="news-item post-<?php echo $index; ?>">
    <div class="news-title"><h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3></div>
    <span class="news-date"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?></span>
    <?php html5wp_excerpt('html5wp_index'); // Build your custom callback length in functions.php ?>
</div>
```

Not sure where you need the ".post-#" classes so I've added them to the ".news-item" element.

I've added the $index variable where I'm storing the current array index. It is starting with 0 but at the start of the loop (at the start of the foreach) I'm increasing the value of index by 1.